# Fix for Windows shortcut Alt+P - Preview Pane - for non-English OS

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Windows in non-English may have a BUG. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works only if the keyboard input is English.

How to fix <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> so that it works no matter what the keyboard input language is? Registry solution is preferred

Comment: What language are you using? I'm unable to recreate the problem.

Comment: I'm running a German Windows 7 with a German (Swiss) Keyboard setting and ALT + P works just fine to show the preview pane in Windows Explorer. Could you please provide more details? Your Windows build, your keyboard settings, language settings, other shortcut keys use by other programs.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Hebrew OS.
Service Pack 1 Build 7601 6.1.7601